# Saving a certain object in an array by user input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make it where I get a user input, that has a string, than a number after it so

> [String] [int]

And what I want to do is save that String onto the number value the integer is... and all I have is here

```
public class test {
    public static String[] mem;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String A=sc.nextLine();
        String[] B=A.split(" ");
        int D;
        switch(B.length) {
        case 1:
            D=0;
            mem[D]=B[0];
            break;
        case 2:
            D=Integer.parseInt(B[1]);
            mem[D]=B[0];
            break;
        default:
                main(null);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(mem.length);
    }
}
```

And it gives me an error which is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ```
> at test.main(test.java:16)
> ```

Comment: why are you passing null to main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of your main method, you have to initialise the mem array.

`mem = new String[n] //n is the number of slots in the array you expect`

You get the null pointer exception because your static mem array is null when you try to assign a value to it (on line 16)